# NeoVim coc.nvim enter key doesn't work to autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, neovim

Recently I rewrote my NeoVim config file from **vim script** to **lua** and everything is working fine, but I have one issue. When I'm using coc.nvim for autocompletion and I select something, hit enter, NeoVim makes a new line and doesn't autocomplete. I found the solution [there](https://superuser.com/questions/246641/vim-completion-always-suppress-the-newline-after-i-select-a-suggestion-with-th), but only for **Vim Script**. **How can I do this in NeoVim Lua?**

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-Y>" : "\<CR>"
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a quite easy you just have to add:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm() : "\<CR>"
```

you have to put this line inside `init.lua`

However, If you use the auto paring package (https://github.com/windwp/nvim-autopairs) with COC it's not going to work.

to check whether it's going to work or not simple run

```
:verbose imap <CR>
```

after you install and setup your package

If nothing is there you are good to go and use my imap that I provide.
If there is any key map that is already binding to the CR (which means enter BTW) then, you have to remap it on the package or use a different key than enter.

In my case, windwp auto paring takes the enter key and that leads to an error.

The solution is to use COC auto pair.
just run `:CocInstall coc-pairs` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think i find the solution!

If you install the plugin via packer, in your init.lua write:

```
require('nvim-autopairs').setup{
  map_cr = false,
}
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm() :
  "\<C-g>u\<c-r>=v:lua.require'nvim-autopairs'.autopairs_cr()\<CR>"
 Maybe you want to use this to enable both <cr> select and wrap enter if no pum window

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding this in your init.lua

```
vim.fn.nvim_command('inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm() : "\\<CR>"')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).